# Loading PHP scripts from /var/www/

Tags: apache-2.4, filesystems

I have Ubuntu 16.04 set up with Apache2 and I'm lost on how I can (if possible) load PHP scripts that aren't in my `var/www/html` but are located in `var/www/php`.

I've tried using `../` to navigate backwards out of the `html` folder and to the `php` folder but the server responds with:

```
POST 192.168.1.95/php/file.php 404 (Not Found)
```

And well it looks like it's trying to find `php/file.php` inside `var/www/html` *(thus giving 404)* but I would like for it to look at `var/www/php/file.php`

Is this possible? If I'm not providing enough information I'll do my best to supply more if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good thing that your webserver does not honour `../` to navigate up the system system tree...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `DocumentRoot` to point to `/var/www/php` instead of `/var/www/html`.

To do this, open `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` in your text editor like vim, and edit the line

`DocumentRoot /var/www/html`

to

`DocumentRoot /var/www/php`

(The file name might be different for other distributions. This filename is correct for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

After saving your changes, you have to restart the Apache Webserver, using

`service apache2 restart` as root.

You might need to use `systemctl restart apache2` if you are using **systemd**.

Comment: Assuming he wants to move his web server's root from /var/www/html to /var/www/php; he could have a current website he wants to keep there.

Comment: Yes, @DarkMoon is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to use a virtual directory for that. That'd let you put, for instance, /var/www/php under your web root so it could show as http://yoursite/php, where http://yoursite is /var/www/html.